# Is there a way to run a single cucumber feature file on autotest?

Tags: cucumber, autotest

I'd like to run just a single cucumber feature file on autotest. I'd like the test to be run, report failures, then run again as soon as I save a change to my code base. Anyone know a way to do this?

--Jack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution myself:

Watchr - https://github.com/mynyml/watchr

It watches whenever you save specified files and runs specified tests at that point. Uses pattern matching.